# Scheduled Talend jobs randomly go to sleep for 45 minutes while doing nothing (JDK 1.8 Talend v6)

Tags: java, windows, performance, java-8, talend

We are experiencing something strange on a production environment. A series of talend jobs (Talend V6, JDK 1.8 .... unluckily the versions are not upgradable for constraints out of our control) are scheduled using windows schedule and work fine on 95% of time, but sometimes they "go to sleep" during an execution and do nothing for 45/50 minutes. It's not always the same job and it's not happening always on the same set of data

An example

2021-12-17 12:57:52 INFO CommandTargetRegistrySingleton:36 - Register : com.lectra.common.command.client.target.http.CommandTargetHttpRemote
2021-12-17 12:57:52 INFO CommandTargetRegistrySingleton:36 - Register : com.lectra.common.command.client.target.http.CommandTargetHttpsRemote
2021-12-17 13:47:29 INFO 002_IMPORT_FABRIC

There is no reason for the 50 minutes passed between the two log lines, in fact if we rerun the same job with the same data, we get few ms of execution time

We have asked the customer to check its servers and be sure antivirus is not scanning the temporary folders used by the jobs.
Being generally short lived jobs (5 minutes of execution time as avg) would be useful to increase Xms size?
Which other performance tips should we follow? Do you have any good reference for jvm 8 performance tuning?

Thanks for any suggestion/answer

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the running Java application via VisualVM:

Detailed article can be found here:
https://community.talend.com/s/article/Using-VisualVM-to-record-Java-Issues

If you're on linux then you can enable JFR (even on Java 8 after doing an upgrade as in 2021 the JFR was backported to OpenJDK) and do a recording during these "hang states".

Once you know what's inside that is blocking you'll be able to make the necessary changes.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will have a look at it... just a thing, I am on Windows, I hope your sentence <<If you're on linux then you can enable JFR (even on Java 8 after doing an upgrade as in 2021 the JFR was backported to OpenJDK) and do a recording during these "hang states">> does not mean I cannot do the same in my setup.

Comment: On windows you have GUI, and you can use VisualVM which is a GUI application. In linux you usually have no GUI hence the alternative solution via JFR.